# ASP.NET Core and View conflict resolution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, plugins

I'm trying to build a plugin system for ASP.NET Core application. I have a folder inside the app called 'Plugins'.

In general, a plugin looks like a folder containing two files: Plugin.dll and Plugin.Views.dll
The app scans this folder and loads these assemblies

```
foreach (var ext in extensionManager.Extensions)
{
    mvcBuilder.AddApplicationPart(ext.Assembly);
    if (ext.ViewsAssembly != null)
    {
        mvcBuilder.AddApplicationPart(ext.ViewsAssembly);
    }
}
```

If these plugins have ViewComponents with the same name I get an error. Model from Plugin1 may be passed into Plugin2's Razor View.

```
The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'Plugin1.Models.MyModel', 
but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'Plugin2.Models.MyModel'
```

How can I resolve this conflict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding this `Target` to my plugins' .csproj files:

```
<Target Name="UpdateTargetPath" BeforeTargets="AssignRazorGenerateTargetPaths">
  <ItemGroup>
    <RazorGenerate Link="$(TargetName)\%(RazorGenerate.RelativeDir)%(RazorGenerate.FileName)%(RazorGenerate.Extension)" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

I took [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51066251/2329644) as a basis. I also delete the `Include` attribute from the `RazorGenerate` tag because it duplicates `RazorCompiledAttribute` in the resulting assembly.

On the host app's side, I extended view location formats with:

```
services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(opts =>
{
    var pluginName = ext.Assembly.GetName().Name;
    opts.ViewLocationFormats.Add($"/{pluginName}/Views/Shared/{{0}}.cshtml");
    opts.ViewLocationFormats.Add($"/{pluginName}/{{1}}/Views/{{0}}.cshtml");
});
```

In the plugin I must specify the fully qualified path to the view:

```
return View($"/{this.GetType().Assembly.GetName().Name}/Views/Path/To/MyView.cshtml", model);
```

Answer (score 0):

> The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type
> 'Plugin1.Models.MyModel',  but this ViewDataDictionary instance
> requires a model item of type 'Plugin2.Models.MyModel'

You can try to use the full name `Plugin2.Models.MyModel` if this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type `Plugin2.Models.MyModel`.So that it will not pass `Plugin1.Models.MyModel` to this ViewDataDictionary.

Comment: How is it supposed to work this way? The problem is not that I pass the model instance of the wrong type. The problem is that ASP.NET Core finds the wrong View (cshtml file) because they have the same name.